# write at specific part of file in python

Tags: python, parsing

I am writing a python command line script that takes a .ldif and two strings.  The strings correspond to a key and a value that I need to insert at the end of each record in the .ldif file.  However, I'm having an issue figuring out how to parse the .ldif file so that I know I'm at the end of a record.  When I reach the end of a record I need to write to the file the two strings (Key: Value) with a colon in between them.

So basically I need to:

1. Parse arguments from the command line (.ldif, string1, string2)
2. Create the string I am going to append to the .ldif
3. Open the .ldif and seek to the end of each record.  Upon reaching the end of a record I need to write the string I created from string1 and string2.
4. When I see the EOF of the .ldif I need to return the .ldif file with the updated records.

Before:

```
    # example.ldif
    dn: Aamir_005_000
    cn: Aamir_25
    givenname: Aamir

    dn: Saul_024
    cn: Saululite
    givenname: Saul
```

After: `python myscript.py ./example.ldif sillyname syllabear`

```
    # example.ldif
    dn: Aamir_005_000
    cn: Aamir_25
    givenname: Aamir
    sillyname: syllabear

    dn: Saul_024
    cn: Saululite
    givenname: Saul
    sillyname: syllabear
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1],'r+') as f1:
    lines=[x.strip() for x in f1]
    f1.truncate(0)
    f1.seek(0)
    for x in lines:
       if x:
         f1.write(x+'\n')
       else:
         f1.write("{0}:{1}\n\n".format(sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3]))
    f1.write("{0}:{1}\n\n".format(sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3]))
```

Comment: Okay cool!  This does exactly what I want it to do, however is there any truth in what @Jarrod said?  If so then I'm trying to write the script using the ldif mod but my python install doesn't recognize my import ldif call

Comment: @FreddieJuliusMonkeyking Actuallu I've no idea about ldif module, by the way where did you installed ldif module on your system?

Comment: I have the module working, I'm just not sure how to use it.  From what I can't tell much from <a href="http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldif.html#module-ldif">this</a> example.  @JarrodRobberson Do you know how I can get similar functionality using the ldif mod?

Answer (score 0):

#### python-ldap and its ldif module

Python has support for LDAP records with the [python-ldap project](http://www.python-ldap.org/) and its [ldif](http://www.python-ldap.org/doc/html/ldif.html) module.

Much like any structured file format, you want to use a robust parser and generator to read the records, manipulate them and write them back out.

You don't want to be trying to parse the file yourself with hacks like regex's and the like, only to have your code break when something in the file changes next week, then the week after that and then a few days after that.

You wouldn't try and inject XML stanzas into an XML file either, you would use an XML parser, inject what you needed and write it back out.

Comment: I'm getting an error when running the example on your link.  Python doesn't recognize the ldif module.

Comment: did you download and install the python-ldap packages?

Comment: Good xml analogy, put it in perspective for me.  Ah, hah ya I should probably be installing the packages to use them xD, thank you!  I'll try it out and get back to you

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but where do the python-ldap files reside so I can dl them?

Comment: seriously you don't see the `Download` link on the python-ldap project page that I linked too?